# Attempting to toggleClass on div is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pull a `toggleClass()` on a class from an id element, e.g:

```
$('#create a').click(function(){
  $('#create div').toggleClass('active');
});
```

and it doesn't wanna toggle the class `active` on the divider.

Here is the button:

```
<a href="#create" id="create" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

and here is the class I'm trying to toggle `active` on:

```
<div class="" id="create">
  <!-- Content Here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$('#create')` instead.

Comment: You are duplicating ID's (#create)

Comment: In the button or divider I'm trying to toggle on?

Comment: `$("#create div")` will look for a div inside an element with the ID of `create`.  You want `$("div#create")` (a div *with* that ID).  Also, as above, IDs *must* be unique or you can't rely on the outcome.

Comment: @mikeywikey  check the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly `#create a` won't match any elements as the `a` element has that id, not a child element of it. You could instead use `a#create` or just `#create`.

Secondly you've duplicated the `create` id on both the `a` and the `div`, when `id` attributes must be unique within a page. You need to use another `id` value to identify the `div` element.

With those issues in mind, try this:

```js
$('#create').click(function(){
  $('#content').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#create" id="create" data-toggle="tab">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">+</i>
</a>
<div class="" id="content">
  Content here...
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is an explanation of the problem and working fix not enough?

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked but for some reason, it's not 'untoggling' the class for me.

Comment: i don't know why people gave -ve marking without telling any reason

Comment: In that case check your CSS in the DOM inspector to ensure that the rule is specific enough to override any existing ones set on the element

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not have the same ID for more than one element.

Second, selectors don't work like you think: `$('#create a')` means "all A elements inside the element with the id = create". Just use `$('#create')`. You could use `$('a#create')`, which means "the A element with id = create", but that's unneccessary since id should always be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you give a unique ids in your DOM.

And then your selectors are wrong.

They  should be

```
$('#create').click(function(){
  $('#creatediv').toggleClass('active'); // given new id to div
});
```

There is no need to mention the div as you have id in hand.